# Django custom display in html of a query

Tags: python, django, database, backend

I want to query database and showing in html, but in my database it's an int like 1233405061023
and i want to display in my template like this 12334050XXX23, it's that possible or i have to create another column with the custom formating like i mentioned above and display that column instead of clean one ?

Answer (score 2):

Do I get it right that you want to replace some digits with "X" in your output?
To achieve this you could either create a separate column in the db and store it that way (use a custom save() method in your model).
An alternative solution might be to reformat it in your view for display

Comment: That's what i want, thanks for your time :)!